# nodejs express - cant set headers

Tags: node.js, express, cheerio, requestjs

using the values submitted by a webfrom served by express to initiate crawl using request + cheerio.

the parts work separately, when put together i get an error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

what's wrong here?

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){

    res.json('processing')        

    crawl(r.keyword, r.tld, r.brand).then(function(d){

       userObject.urlCache = d;

     }) 
})
```

Comment: the error mean that the response is sent twice. The reason is not clear with this code. Do you run post request treatments ? Can you also carefully bind all error handlers ? http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/10/01/javascript-promises-and-error-handling.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`res.json('processing')` will send a response. You cannot modify the headers after sending a response. It is not clear from you code snippet what is modifying the response after it is being sent.

For more info on the express response object: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

Also there are more response options than res.json. You are not really sending json in your example. You might want `res.send('processing')`, but that will not fix your set header issue..

Answer (score 0):

You should set the header first and then send the request out.

```
res.setHeader('charset', 'utf-8');
res.send('processing');
```